# Problem in understanding Nakayama's lemma.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

**Nakayama's lemma** $:$

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $IM=M,$ then there exists $r \in R$ such that $r \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ I)$ and $rM = 0.$

In order to prove this lemma we need the following theorem.

**Theorem** $:$

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $\varphi : M \longrightarrow M$ be an $R$-module homomorphism and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $\varphi (M) \subseteq IM.$ Then there is a relation of the form

$${\varphi}^n + a_1 {\varphi}^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n = 0,\ a_i \in I.$$

$\text{for some}\ n.$

Our instructor gave a proof of this theorem and I have understood it on my own. After the proof of this theorem it has been stated in the lecture notes that **Nakayama's lemma** directly follows from the above theorem by taking $\varphi = \text{id}_M.$ But I find difficulty to understand this. Also I find difficulty to understand the second assertion made in the lemma which is $rM=0.$ The problem is that since $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then $rM = r(IM) = (rI)M = IM = M = 0.$ So $rM = 0 \implies M=0.$ Where have I done mistakes? Would anybody please help overcoming me from this situation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you take $\phi = \operatorname{id}$, the relation takes the form $(1+\sum a_i) \operatorname{id} = 0$ because $\operatorname{id} ^ m =\operatorname{id}$.   Since the $a_i \in I$, this says $(1+j)M = 0$ for some $j \in I$. Now $1+j$ is the $r$ from Nakayama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question note $\varphi^n = \varphi = \text{id}$ in the special case. Thus $$\varphi\cdot(1+a_1+\cdots+a_n)=0$$ so $r= 1 + \sum a_i$ works.

As for your second question, $rI \subset I$ is not necessarily equality so you can only deduce $rM \subset M$ which is of course true.

Comment: What do you mean $\varphi \cdot (1+a_1+\cdots+a_n) = 0?$

Comment: What does $r \equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\ I)$ mean to say? Does it not mean to say that $r+I = 1+I$?

Comment: Just the same thing as the given notation in the problem, for all $m\in M$ this equation holds, or alternateively it’s an equality of functions. The dot is so as not to confuse multiplication with function notation

Comment: It means $r = 1+ a$ for some $a\in I$, or equivalently your statement.

Comment: Yeah now I have understood what actually is going on here. Thanks @Ben for your help.